# Mvc List Strongly type View DropDownListFor not showing current value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have following `dropdownlistfor` control

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => item.RelationShipId, new SelectList(ViewBag.RelationShip,"Id", "Title"), new { @id = "ddl_" + @item.UserID, @class = "form-control", onchange = "update(this,'" + @item.UserID + "','" + @item.SentByUserId + "');" })
```

I bind this strongly type view like this `@model List<MvcUI.Models.UserDetails>`

In `ViewBag.RelationShip` I have following list

```
public static List<IDTitleDTO> DataTableToRelationshipList(this DataTable table)
{
        var list = table.AsEnumerable()
            .Select(dr =>
                new IDTitleDTO
                {
                    Id = dr.Field<int>("RelationShipId"),
                    Title = dr.Field<string>("RelationShipName")
                }).ToList();
        return list;
}
```

I am passing List Of `UserDetails` model to my view. Here is my `UserDetails` Model

```
public class UserFriendDetails
{
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public int? RelationShipId { get; set; }
    ....
    ...
    Other fields
}
```

Suppose in a list I have 3 record. Out of them 2 records RelationShipId is null. If it's null then I am setting -1 which is -- Select --. In remaining one record I have RelationShipId suppose I have 13. When view opens It is binding -- Select -- for first two record. But for 3rd record it is not binding appropriate value from ViewBag. I can't figure it out where is the issue. Can some one help me to solve this?

### EDIT

Here I have created one simple action i.e. user

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult User()
{
    var model = new List<UserDetails>();
    model.Add(new UserDetails { Id = 1, Fname = "ajay", RelationId = 3});
    model.Add(new UserDetails { Id = 2, Fname = "vijay", RelationId = 1 });
    model.Add(new UserDetails { Id = 3, Fname = "John", RelationId = 2 });

    var rList = new List<IdTitleDTO>();
    rList.Add(new IdTitleDTO { Id = 1 , Title = "M"});
    rList.Add(new IdTitleDTO { Id = 2, Title = "F" });
    rList.Add(new IdTitleDTO { Id = 3, Title = "B" });

    ViewBag.Rel = rList;
    return View(model);
}
```

Here is my `user.cshtml`

```
@model List<WebApplicationDropDown.Models.UserDetails>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Fname
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @*@foreach (var item in Model) {*@
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].Fname)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => Model[i].RelationId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Rel, "Id", "Title"), "--Select--")
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

In this View it is not binding relationId. By default it is showing `-- Select --` instead of showing following relation

```
ajay - B
Vijay - M
John - F
```

Please see following image

[image]

### New EDIT

Editor template UserDetails.`cshtml`

```
@model WebApplicationDropDown.Models.UserDetails


@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RelationId, (SelectList)ViewData["RelationShipList"])
```

**View.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplicationDropDown.Models.UserDetails>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Fname
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fname)
            </td>
            <td>
                @*@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.RelationId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Rel, "Id", "Title"), "--Select--")*@
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m, new { RelationShipList = new SelectList(ViewBag.Rel, "Id", "Title") })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Please See following screenshot

[image]

Comment: I really can't quite figure out what you're asking here...  You say you have 3 records, then explain only 2 of them.. then you say something that makes no sense...

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Suppose in a list I have 3 record. Out of them 2 records `RelationShipId` is null. If it's null then I am setting -1 which is **-- Select --**. In remaining one record I have `RelationShipId` suppose I have 13. When view opens It is binding -- Select -- for first two record. But for 3rd record it is not binding appropriate value from ViewBag.

Comment: You appear to generating the dropdownlists in a `foreach` loop, which generates duplicate `id` attributes (invalid html) and duplicate `name` attributes which have no relationship to a collection and therefore will not bind to anything

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for reply. How can I avoid this duplications?

Comment: You need to use a `for` loop and set the selected item using the overload of `SelectList` that accepts `selectedValue` or better use a custom `EditorTemplate` and pass the select list to the template using `addtionalViewData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom `EditorTemplate` for type of `UserFriendDetails`

In `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/UserFriendDetails.cshtml`

```
@model UserFriendDetails
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
....
@Html.DropDownLstFor(m => m.RelationShipId, (SelectList)ViewData["RelationShipList"])
```

Then in the main view, pass the `SelectList` to the template using additional view data

```
@model IEnumerable<UserFriendDetails>
....
@Html.EditorFor(m => m, new { RelationShipList = new SelectList(ViewBag.RelationShip,"Id", "Title") })
```

This will generate the correct name attributes to bind to you collection, for example

```
<select name="[0].RelationShipId" ..>
<select name="[1].RelationShipId" ..>
```

and select the correct option based on the value of each `RelationShipId` property.

Side note: I suggest you remove the `new { @id = "ddl_" + @item.UserID,...` and use the default `id` generated by the helper. Its not clear what the `onchange` attribute is doing but I also suggest you use [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) rather than polluting your markup with behavior.

Comment: Thanks I will try and let you know.

Comment: Just to expand on Erik's answer, what do you mean setting a value to `-1` means `--Select--`? Do **not** add an option with value = -1 and associated text = "--Select--". You add a default `null` option using the `labelOption` parameter of the `SelectList` constructor as Erik has indicated.

Comment: Yes `-1` means `-- Select --`.

Comment: Do not do that. You will have other issues with validation. You table should **not** have a row with `RelationShipId = -1` and `RelationShipName` = "--Select--"` If you want nulls, make the `RelationShipId ` nullable and use `@Html.DropDownLstFor(m => m.RelationShipId, (SelectList)ViewData["RelationShipList"], "--Please Select--")`

Comment: Ok. I will change that. But I can validate if there is `-1` is selected.

Comment: Have you tried my answer (which works)? If you want to use the `for` loop, you need to use the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553(v=vs.118).aspx) that accepts `Object selectedValue`, for example `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].RelationId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Rel, "Id", "Title", Model[i].RelationId), "--Select--")` but this is not very efficient since your constructing a new `SelectList` in each iteration.

Comment: I tried you editortemplate solution. It is showing me three dropdown in front of each `Fname` .  Because there are three record in dropdown list i.e. M,F,B

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand your comment. Is something not working as expected? (based on your edited question, you should see 'ajay' and the associated option will be 'B', and 'vijay' with 'M' and 'John' with 'F') Did you use the code I showed (or did you also do some kind of loop as well which is not what I showed)?

Comment: What you have shown is not possible (3 dropdowns wont be rendered unless your have 3 dropdowns in your view) so you have some other code that you have not shown causing that. But is all very confusing because you keep changing the names of the models and their properties (UserFriendDetails vs UserDetails, RelationShipId vs RelationId, ViewBag.RelationShip vs ViewBag.Rel)

Comment: Actually I have created one sample project which is using UserDetails model which contain `RelationId`. I have mentioned it in **EDIT**. I showed you all my view code, controller code, editor template code.

Comment: You can't have showed all the code, because your `EditorTemplate` does not have a `DisplayFor(m => m.FName)` yet you screen shot shows that you render it.

Comment: If I added `DisplayFor` then it is showing me `Fname` in front of each Dropdown.

Comment: Then you mixing something up. The answer I showed you does not have any kind of a loop (a `for` or `foreach` statement) but clearly you are using a loop of some kind. `@Html.EditorFor(m => m) will render the collection correctly. It does not go inside a loop.

Comment: See my View.cshtml in New Edit. I have added all code from my view.

Comment: Read my answer again carefully. Remove the `foreach` loop (all 12 lines of code)  and replace it with the following 1 line of code `@Html.EditorFor(m => m, new { RelationShipList = new SelectList(ViewBag.Rel, "Id", "Title") })`

Comment: Then in the `EditorTemplate`, add `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Fname)` and any other elements that you want to render for typeof `UserDetail`

Comment: Oh Ok. But In my actual project there are lots of fields to show. So I need to add all these in Editor template ?

Comment: Yes, as I showed in my answer - if you want a textbox for property `UserName` then the template needs to include `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)` etc.

Comment: I am not getting how editor template knows the fname when are passing `RelationShipList` which is `ViewBag.RelationShip` only.

Comment: `Html.EditorFor(m => m,` means you are passing the main views model to the template which is `IEnumerable<UserDetail>` The template is `@model UserDetail` and `EditorFor` is smart enough to know its a collection, and renders each `UserDetail` object correctly. The second parameter of `EditorFor()` is passing the `SelectList` to the editor as **additional** view data (i.e. in **addition** to the model)

Comment: Oh Ok. Thanks for your help. I will try to implement it in my project.

Comment: I got solution. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, I can't quite figure out what you're asking, but what I can figure out is that you're doing a few things wrong here.

First, you should not be using "-1" for default..  You are using a nullable field RelationShipId, and you should make RelaitonShipId null when you want it unselected, then you use the "option label" default string parameter of DropDownListFor to place the text for this.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => item.RelationShipId, 
     new SelectList(ViewBag.RelationShip,"Id", "Title"), 
     "--Select--", 
     new { @id = "ddl_" + @item.UserID, @class = "form-control", 
       onchange = "update(this,'" + @item.UserID + "','" + @item.SentByUserId + "');" })
```

This allows model binding and validation to work, so if you have a required validation, if RelationShipId is null ("--Select--" is selected) then it will fail to validate.

Comment: Thank you for reply. If have a null value in RelationshipId then I am setting -1 to it. At that time it is showing -- Select --. But If there is any other relationid suppose 13 then it is not showing the value of 13 while binding.

Comment: The view is strongly type view `@model List<LifetronsMvcUI.Models.UserDetails>`

Comment: @AjayPunekar - MVC does not support using array indexes in expressions with `DropDownListFor()` and selecting the existing value.  I don't know if it's a bug or design limitation, but you can't use it this way.  Either set the Selected value in the SelectList, or use the EditorTemplate method that Stephen suggested (which is much cleaner anyways)

Comment: I got solution. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution for multiple dropdown on `View`

```
<select class="form-control" id="ddl_@item.UserID" name="ddl_@item.UserID" onchange = "update(this,'@item.UserID','@item.SentByUserId');">
    @foreach (var rel in listRelations)
    {
        <option @if (string.Compare(item.RelationShipId.ToString(), rel.Id.ToString(), true) == 0)
                { @Html.Raw("selected")  } value="@rel.Id">@rel.Title</option>
    }
</select>
```

here `listRelations` is `ViewBag` of type `var listRelations = ViewBag.RelationShip as List<IDTitleDTO>;`

Comment: Is this a joke? If my answer did not work then your doing something else wrong. What a dreadful solution.