# SelectListItem not setting selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have these classes.

```
public class Store {
  // constructor
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
}

public class Stock {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int StoreId { get; set; }
  public int ProductId { get; set; }

  public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
  public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product {
  // constructor
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public ICollection<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
}

public class Order {
  // constructor
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem {
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public ICollection<Store> Stores { get; set; }
  public Item Item { get; set; }
  public Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

Fluid api:

```
public class OrderItemMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrderItem> {
  public OrderItemMap() {
    HasMany(i => i.Stores)
      .WithMany()
      .Map(m => {
          m.MapLeftKey("OrderItemId");
          m.MapRightKey("StoreId");
          m.ToTable("FromStore");
        });
  }
}
```

Now, for instance I have created an order and set my details and also **the item's store** as to where they should get the item to deliver it. **Note: An item can have many stores**.

My problem is.. If the user wants to **Edit** the order. I don't know how to display the list of stores as dropdown and it's selected value.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
var order = _db.Orders.Find(orderId);
var orderVm = new EditOrderVm {
  OrderId = order.Id,
  OrderItems = order
               .OrderItems
               .Select(o => new EditOrderItemVm {
                 OrderItemId = o.Id,
                 OrderId = o.OrderId,
                 ProductId = o.ProductId,
                 Stores = (from sc in o.Product.Stocks
                           from st in o.Stores.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select new {
                             Id = sc.Store.Id,
                             Name = sc.Store.Name
                           }).ToSelectList(s => s.Name, s => s.Id, s => true)
               })
}
```

My VM:

```
public class EditOrderItemVm {
  // removed some for brevity
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Storses { get; set; }
}
```

My helper (ain't mine)

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T, TTextProperty, TValueProperty>(this IEnumerable<T> instance, Func<T, TTextProperty> text, Func<T, TValueProperty> value, Func<T, bool> selectedItem = null)
        {
            return instance.Select(t => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = Convert.ToString(text(t)),
                Value = Convert.ToString(value(t)),
                Selected = selectedItem != null && selectedItem(t)
            });
        }
```

My View:

```
@Model.OrderNumber
@foreach(var item in Model.OrderItems) {

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => item.StoreId, item.Stores, "Select store")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.StoreId)
}
```

With the query above, I can populate the dropdown with the list of stores as to where the product is stored but i don't know how to set of what was selected during creation of order.

It would be great if I can populate the dropdown with the list of stores as to where the item is stored and also set it's selected value.

Comment: As i see from your code, all elements are `Selected = true`, here you say that `.ToSelectList(s => s.Name, s => s.Id, s => true)`

Comment: Can you show your view also?

Comment: @adricadar what do you suggest to be done? How can I select what's currently selected? I'm outside the scope of the joined table.

Comment: Where is the selected store supposed to come from? You don't have a StoreId in your Order class.

Comment: you have something wrong with your design as the OrderItem should have a ICollection<Product> at least not stores...

Comment: @SherifAhmed Oh. I omit this property in the question `public virtual Product Product { get; set; }`

Comment: @BoyPasmo sorry but also where is The Item Entity?

Comment: My fault. Should be `Product` not `Item`

Comment: OK @BoyPasmo thats great ... so when some one purchase a Product you are storing the Product in the OrderItem and also u should store the store from where this user purchased this item... so when binding in the edit u will use this storeId to get the selected one.

Comment: Yes I am storing the store where the user purchased the item but on a different table called `FromStore`

Comment: I assume you did not understand my comment on your last question. none of this can work because you are generating your dropdown in a `foreach` loop. If you inspect the html, you will see that every `<select>` has the same `id` attribute (invalid html) and `name` attribute which has no relationship to your model and therefore will not bind on postback. I suggest you start by looking at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29446590/mvc-list-strongly-type-view-dropdownlistfor-not-showing-current-value/29466350#29466350)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line should look like this, You have to take **all your stores** from db and select those who are involved in current order.

```
var order = _db.Orders.Find(orderId);
var stores = _db.Stores; // take all stores from DB
var orderVm = new EditOrderVm {
  OrderId = order.Id,
  OrderItems = order
               .OrderItems
               .Select(o => new EditOrderItemVm {
                 OrderItemId = o.Id,
                 OrderId = o.OrderId,
                 ProductId = o.ProductId,
                 Stores = (from st in stores // all stores
                           select new {
                             Id = st.Id,
                             Name = st.Name
                        }).ToSelectList(
                            s => s.Name,
                            s => s.Id, 
                            s => o.Stores.Any(sto => sto.Id == s.Id) //select only existing stores
                        )

               })
}
```

Comment: it will be the same as all of the store will be selected

Comment: @SherifAhmed i modified my answer, now should be correct :).

Comment: @BoyPasmo here `from st in stores` to make the entire list of stores.

Comment: @adricadar sorry about that. didn't realize. another quick question tho. do you think there is something wrong in my view? I just use your answer and works fine but when I try to post it. the `StoreId` is null.

Comment: @BoyPasmo the view looks fine, i don't know why the mapping is not done, it's a partial view this?

Comment: The result html tag is `<select id="item_StoreId" name="item.StoreId">...</select>`. Do you think it has something to do with this?

Comment: @BoyPasmo definetly, this is the problem

Comment: What should be done in this case? I really have no idea.

Comment: Hi. I used the `@Html.DropdownList("OrderItem[index].StorehouseId", item.Storehouse, "select")` thank you so much!

Comment: Forget what i said early, i would make a template :). that will have the code that you showed me in the comment. The problem that you faced in the view was because MVC was unable to detect that you have an array of DropDownList and didn't put that index :). usualy `EditorFor` figure this out by default on textboxes but on dropdown i never tried.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `s => true`, you have to do it like
`s => s.Id == YOUR_CURRENT_STORE_Id`.

Comment: How do you do that? I'm outside the scope of the joined table.

Comment: I'm not joining with any table ... for sure the logging user have the current storeId... so just use this current store id in the predicate to get the selected store.

Comment: @BoyPasmo .. as I'm expecting that this order in the creating stage when the user make an order you stored the store which the user had purchased the item from. so when editing you must get that store. am right?

Comment: Dear @BoyPasmo ... you must join this table also and in the line which I mention you should also should do it like that  `s => s.Id == FromStoreTable.StoreId`